# Cant retrieve JSON data more than one time from URL C#

Tags: c#, json, youtube-api

I am programming a Windows form app that will search and gets music from YouTube. But when I try to get music JSON data more than one time, I am getting this error when instantiating `WebClient()`.

Here is my code:

```
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
{
    string JSON_Data = webClient.DownloadString(url_request);
    insancil_adres = new sarki();
    insancil_adres = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<sarki>(JSON_Data);
}
```

> ERROR: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException'
>   occurred in System.dll
>
> Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (400).

And also the code is attached to a button, so every time the button is clicked the code is working again and again but in this case it is working just one time.

Comment: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Have you checked what `url_request` looks like in the debugger?

Comment: `url_request ` is youtube api HTTP request in string format. I think problem is about instantiating `WebClient()`class more than once with same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I couldn't find any proper solution so I tried to approach problem from different way. Finally i found solution by oppening a new form every time i clicked the button that run the code i gave in question